# Is there a way to get Hulu to work on Boxee?

Tags: hulu, boxee

I heard that they were compatible?

Comment: Boxee is a home theater PC program no ? You would get a better answer that is on-topic in superuser.com

Answer (score 1):

Hulu and Boxee have a [long](http://www.mediabistro.com/webnewser/this-is-why-hulu-blocked-boxee_b5986), [colorful](http://mashable.com/2009/05/28/boxee-hulu-desktop/) [history](http://mashable.com/2010/02/04/congress-why-did-hulu-block-boxee/) [together](http://www.afterdawn.com/news/article.cfm/2009/03/07/hulu_blocks_boxee_rss_feed_hack_boxee_fights_back).  For a while it worked, then it stopped working, then it started working again.  So they were compatible.  Sort of.  Whether it will work again in the future is a topic of pure speculation at this point (Though I certainly hope it will).

Comment: Editorial: Hulu is full of crap on this one.  (Though Hulu and the content broadcasters behind Hulu have passed the blame back and forth enough that it's totally unclear which of the two is trying to block Boxee.)

Comment: It's probably the case that Hulu was only able to license certain content by promising the owners that it would only be shown on computer screens, never TV screens. The content owners have still not figured out convergence, I guess.

Comment: Yeah, the problem is, that distinction is meaningless anymore.  The broadcast companies need to figure that out, and fast.